# How to call generic Method from generic Interface c#?

Tags: c#, reflection, masstransit, mediator

**Error Message**:System.ArgumentException: 'Object of type '<>f__AnonymousType2`1[System.String]' cannot be converted to type 'ConsoleApp2.IRequestSimple'

There are my types  Request/Response

```
    public interface IRequestSimple
    {
        public string Field { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IResponseSimple
    {
        public string Answer { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyConsumer : IConsumer<IRequestSimple>
    {
        public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<IRequestSimple> context)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(context.Message.Field);
            await context.RespondAsync<IResponseSimple>(new { Answer = "Good job" });
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to call GetResponse but using reflection

```
var client = mediator.CreateRequestClient<IRequestSimple>();
var response = client.GetResponse<IResponseSimple>(new { });
```

There is my issue, I need to specify type to calling GetResponse

```
var requestType = typeof(IRequestSimple);
var responseType = typeof(IResponseSimple);
            
Type type = mediator.GetType();
var methodInfo = typeof(IClientFactory).GetMethods().Where(s => s.Name == "CreateRequestClient" && s.IsGenericMethod).First();
var genericMethod = methodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(requestType);
dynamic requestClient = genericMethod.Invoke(mediator, new object[] { Missing.Value });

Type type1 = requestClient.GetType();
var methodInfo1 = type1 .GetMethods().Where(s => s.Name == "GetResponse").First();
var genericMethod1 = methodInfo1.MakeGenericMethod(responseType);
//Here is my requestClient should be with specified type
var task = (Task)genericMethod1.Invoke(requestClient, new object[] { new { Field = "1" }, Missing.Value, Missing.Value });
await task.ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: You haven't said what the problem is, such as an error message. But from what I can infer, `requestClient` is an `IRequestClient<Something>` but you try to use it as an `IRequestClient<object>`. That kind of generic variance is not supported. Similarly, you can't cast `List<string>` to `List<object>` even though `string` can be cast to `object`. Declaring it as `dynamic` means nothing because you're not using dynamic dispatch.

Comment: I got error message `System.Reflection.TargetException: 'Object does not match target type.'`
So basically I need to call GetResponse generic method

Comment: Then my comment is on point. You're trying to call `IRequestClient<object>.GetResponse` on something that's not an `IRequestClient<object>`.

Comment: What can you advise here? I can not get typeof  IRequestClient<something> but I have type of generic interface which I need to cast

Comment: `var genericMethod1 = requestClient.GetType().GetMethods().Where(s => s.Name == "GetResponse").First();`  You don't need `methodInfo1`.

Comment: The `requestClient.GetType()` part gets the *actual* type, which will be close-constructed so you don't need `MakeGenericMethod`. And while you're at it, get rid of `dynamic` because you don't need the `GetType` call to be dynamically dispatched. Declare it as `object` instead.

Comment: Thanks.
I changed the code
`Type type1 = requestClient.GetType();`
`var methodInfo1 = type1.GetMethods().Where(s => s.Name == "GetResponse" && s.IsGenericMethod).First();`
`var genericMethod1 = methodInfo1.MakeGenericMethod(responseType);`
`var task = (Task)genericMethod1.Invoke(requestClient, new object[] { new { Field = "1" }, Missing.Value, Missing.Value });`
I got another error message:
System.ArgumentException: 'Object of type '<>f__AnonymousType2`1[System.String]' cannot be converted to type 'ConsoleApp2.IRequestSimple'.'

Comment: You don't need `MakeGenericMethod`. In your version, `methodInfo1` is already close-constructed.

Comment: GetResponse accept another generic type, that type I need to specify to get specific response
so `IRequestClient<TRequest>` have method  `GetResponse<T>`

Comment: I see... well, you left out those details. It looked like you were using `MakeGenericMethod` to resolve the type parameter of `IRequestClient`, which was already resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I just create method and invoke that

```
public static async Task<Tout> GetResponse<Tin, Tout>(object request) where Tin : class where Tout : class
{
  var requestClient = Program.mediator.CreateRequestClient<Tin>();
  var response = await requestClient.GetResponse<Tout>(request);
  return response.Message;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).